# How can I cross compile libSSL as a dynamic librairy?

Tags: dll, cross-compiling, libssl

Does anybody knows how can I cross compile libSSL as a dynamic librairy using openWRT toolchain?

Thanks for your answers and have a nice day

Answer (score 0):

Openwrt already provides libssl in packages, simply take feeds update and select openssl in make menuconfig, then compile the openwrt build.